# ListBox SelectionChanged event with MVVM and CommandParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I'm developing a MVVM app with WPF, C# and .NET Framework 4.6.1.

I'm trying to implement `ListBox SelectionChanged` event using MVVM. To do it I have done this:

Install nuget package: `PM> Install-Package System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF`.
Add `xmlns:interactivity="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"` on xaml.
Add this code to my `ListBox` in xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxTrzType" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25" ItemsSource="{Binding TrzTypes}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ListBoxTrzTypeSelectionChanged}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listBoxTrzType, Path=SelectedItem}">
            </interactivity:InvokeCommandAction>
        </interactivity:EventTrigger>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

On ViewModel I have:

```
public ICommand ListBoxTrzTypeSelectionChanged
{
    get { return new DelegateCommand(TrzTypeSelectionChanged); }
}

private void TrzTypeSelectionChanged()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

And `DelegateCommand` class:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _action;

    public DelegateCommand(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

#pragma warning disable 67
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged { add { } remove { } }
#pragma warning restore 67
}
```

But my problem is that I don't know how to pass `CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listBoxTrzType, Path=SelectedItem}"` to `private void TrzTypeSelectionChanged()`.

I've been searching a lot on Internet and I haven't found any example (only examples with `CanExecute`).

How do I have to modify my `ViewModel` class to access `SelectedItem` parameter?

Answer (score 9):

Actually, to use interaction behaviors for such task is overkill.
You even don't need a command here. It's enough to add `SelectedItem` property into view model and listen for property changes:

```
public class SomeVm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // INPC implementation is omitted

    public IEnumerable<SomeType> Items { get; }
    public SomeType SelectedItem
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedItem != value)
            {
                selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                // do what you want, when property changes
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Comment: What happens if `SelectionMode= "Multiple". Then we will have to use Triggers right?

Comment: No, there's more straightforward MVVM-approach, which uses `IsSelected` property in list item view model and `ItemContainerStyle`. IMO, interaction triggers are useful, when there's some event, which one can't "map" to view model properties.

Comment: So if I have usercontrol where a UI element signifies selection. Then can I update the UI for that using `IsSelected` or will I have to override ItemTemplate for selection and discard usercontrol. Which would you advise?

Comment: There is another stack overflow post which suggests using the other approach, i think that's why he chose it. This one works perfectly.

Comment: I like this answer, and used it for my needs, but technically, this creates the interaction as a single click instead of a double click which is used in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In your `DelegateCommand`
change `private readonly Action _action;` to `private readonly Action<object> _action;` then in your execute method

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    _action.Invoke(parameter);
}
```

Now your `ViewModel` function needs to look like this:

```
private void TrzTypeSelectionChanged(object parameter)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

And you are good to go.